DataTables multiple cells in child row
I'm wanting to display multiple  tags in a child row, and I'm having difficulty doing this.  Rather than the child row displaying like <tr><td colspan=18">...</td></tr> I want it to display like: <tr><td colspan="3"></td><td colspan="15">...</td></tr>.Looking at the documentation it states:

I'm having difficulty setting the data type to a node and not a string.  Here is the code I have currently:
"createdRow": function (row, data, index) {
    table.row(row).child(format(data)).show();
},

